# Builder C++, строка char

Tags: c++, c++builder, char, строки

Имеется строка а типа char вводимая в Edit1.

```
 AnsiString Temp=Edit1->Text;
  int n;  char* a;
  a = new char[n];
  a =Temp.c_str();
  n=strlen(a);
```

Ввел через цикл строку 123.
Если просто выводить элемент, то он выводится нормально

```
 Memo1->Lines->Add(a[i]);
```

Выводит 1.
Но если передать значение другой переменной типа int или произвести действие:

```
int k=a[i]+1; 
Memo1->Lines->Add(a[i]);
Memo1->Lines->Add(a[i]+1);
```

Выводит 49 и 50 соответственно.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: k=atoi(a[i]); 
не работает, выводит ошибку:
Cannot convert 'int' to 'const char *'

Comment: Вы путаете символ и код символа. Код символа `'1'` вовсе не равен 1.

Comment: Допустим, а как, всё таки, правильно сделать?

Comment: А что вы _хотите_ сделать? Какой должен получиться результат?

Comment: Работать с введёнными значениями. То есть, если ввёл 123, то и вывод и арифметические действия должны производиться с 1, 2 и 3.

Comment: Тогда разбейте строку не на _символы_, а на _подстроки_, превратите их в числа, и работайте.

Comment: Так мне что-то  вроде этого и нужно, знал как-сделал бы. Вопрос наверное в том, как эту подстроку превратить в число?

Comment: Ну так есть же в ответе! Получение подстроки — `SubString`, превращение в число — `StrToInt`.

Answer (score 1):

Используй функции из **SysUtils**: **StrToInt** / **IntToStr**

```
int i1, i2;
i1 = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
i2 = StrToInt(Edit2->Text);
ShowMessage(IntToStr(i1 + i2));
```

Comment: Так не подходит.

Comment: @Sylar: Почему?

Comment: Нужно ввести строку элементов 5, 10 , 20 (и неизвестно сколько) и ля каждого свой Edit что ли?
Вообще мне нужно создать массив элементов, цифры и арифметические знаки, чтобы потом преобразовать.

Comment: @Sylar: там не Edit, а Edit->Text что есть тот же AnsiString, который можно распарсить через SubString в цикле.

Comment: А можно чем-то вроде SubString удалить подстроку, заменить на другую?

Comment: Ну читай справку по AnsiString: Delete \ Insert